# Override css of Angular2 ADF component

Tags: css, angular, components, overriding, alfresco

I am using Angular2 with the Alfresco Application Development Framework (ADF 1.7.0) and would like to decrease the row height of the document-list component. I am not entirely sure how to override the CSS properties of this component.

What I have already tried is to set the ecapsulation of AppComponent to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`. Then I added the following CSS to `app.component.css`

```
:host /deep/ .adf-data-table[_ngcontent-c9] tbody[_ngcontent-c9] tr[_ngcontent-c9] {
    height: 36px;
}

:host /deep/ .adf-data-table[_ngcontent-c9] td[_ngcontent-c9] {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

I found the selector `.adf-data-table[_ngcontent-c9] tbody[_ngcontent-c9] tr[_ngcontent-c9]` in the Browser console. The problem is that `[_ngcontent-c9]` can change and then my changes don't apply anymore.

I have also tried this selector: `.adf-data-table tbody tr` but then my changes don't override the default properties.

What can I do to override the default properties of the document-list component without explicitly using `[_ngcontent-c9]` in the selector?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should probably use `::ng-deep` as described in [this blog post](https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-css-in-angular-4a52d4bd2700) because `/deep/` is deprecated. You shouldn't need the `[_ngcontent-c9]` if your css is [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) enough. (If it isn't try using an ID or a unique class). It will be hard to create a solution without a [mcve], if you could create a [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5) that would really help

Comment: The solution was to use a more specific selector, thanks @0mpurdy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `::ng-deep` as described in [this blog post](https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-css-in-angular-4a52d4bd2700) because /deep/ is deprecated.

You shouldn't need the `[_ngcontent-c9]` if your css is [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) enough. (If it isn't, try using an ID or a unique class).

Answer (score 0):

As of the ADF 2.3.0 most of the components have View encapsulation turned off to simplify external customization. Similar to Angular Material components, most of the ADF components have CSS class names as their selectors.

For example:

```
 <adf-login class="adf-login>
```

So you can create your styles based on either component selectors or component class names.

You may also want taking a look at the [Theming guide](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components/blob/master/docs/user-guide/theming.md).